# jmeter: access testplan name in sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter

We are developing some test cases using JSR-223 samplers ( groovy lanquage). We have some configuration information that is loaded at run time that keys off the TestPlan name. I don't see a means for accessing the testplan or name from the sampler, or sampler result. Is there a means to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String script = FileServer.getFileServer().getScriptName();
```

[image: File Server Demo]

You can do the same using [__TestPlanName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__TestPlanName) function passing via "Parameters" section

References:

- [FileServer class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#getScriptName())
- [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)

---

UPDATE

Theoretically it is possible to access JMeter Test Plan tree, but remember, every time you bypass Java limitation using Reflection somewhere somehow a kitten dies.

Example code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Collection;

StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine();
Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);
HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine);

SearchByClass<TestPlan> testPlans = new SearchByClass<>(TestPlan.class);
testPlanTree.traverse(testPlans);
Collection<TestPlan> testPlansRes = testPlans.getSearchResults();

for (TestPlan testPlan : testPlansRes) {
    log.info(testPlan.getProperty("TestElement.name").toString());
}
```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 - get test plan name]

You can check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using JMeter and Java API.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. We use the name of the Test Plan, not the name of the jmx file to manage some configuration we use in our tests. So for example instead of Test Plan the first icon may show Sensor-functional-tests. Users know that the configuration file that correlates to this test has that specific name so we would like our JSR Samplers  to be able to load the config file from that particular name. Currently we are using a variable to accommodate this, but it means setting the same information in two places, the variable declaration and the test plan name.

Comment: Thank you. Is there ever going to be more than one test plan? I don't see how that could be configured.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to have > 1 test plan